How to send stream response to http request from node worker thread
I am doing expensive server-side rendering in nodejs worker thread. After all computations are finished I want to stream response to http response. Is there any way except sending chunks via messages?
I want to avoid buffering whole response to string, sending it to main worker and sending response as one big string. I know that main worker and worker thread cannot share stream, but maybe is it possible somehow to transfer ownership or access to request from main thread to worker?

a few good links here: https://www.google.com/search?q=node+buffer+transfer+worker but please post some code examples, or at least mention what framework you're using like express, or..?

No framework, just vanilla nodejs and buffer is not stream. That's the point.

Okay, no framework (you should mention that in the question). But without any sample code it's hard to say what you're doing: using HTTP or HTTP/2 for example? btw. Response.body is a Transferable object, if that helps.
